# Compact operators on Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I m working on the following problem:

Let $K:H\rightarrow H$ be a compact operator on a Hilbert space. Show that if there exists a sequence $(u_n)_n\in H$ such that $K(u_n)$ is orthonormal, then $|u_n|\rightarrow \infty$.

Here is my argument: It is suffice to show for all $u\in H$, there exists $M>0$ such that $|u_n-u|\geq M$, that is $(u_n)$ has no limit in $H$. Suppose $u_n\rightarrow u$ (all the convergence are strong in my argument), then $Ku_n\rightarrow Ku$. I claim that we can extract a subsequence $(Ku_{n_k})_k$ that is divergent. Denote $E_k=\overline{span\{Ku_{n_k}\}}$,  and we may choose $Ku_{n_k}$ such that $||Ku_{n_k}||=1$ (trivial) and $dist(Ku_{n_{k+1}}, E_k)\geq 1/2$. So $|Ku_{n_k}-Ku_{n_{k+1}}|\geq 1/2$ for all $k$, which violates the convergence of the sequence $Ku_n$.

Since I did not use the fact that $K$ is a compact operator, there must be something wrong with the proof. Can someone let me know which part is problematic? Any hints for the right approach?

Comment: I don't even understand the first step of your argument.  Why does this suffice?  Are you planning to show that $|u_n - u|\ge M$ for some $n$, all $n$, or what?

Comment: right, that make sense only in real numbers to show $u_n$ does not converge to $u$

Comment: You only showed that the sequence $(u_n)$ cannot be convergent. You still need to show that $\|u_n\|\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd proceed as follows:

- An orthonormal set has no limit point.
- Therefore, any set containing an infinite orthonormal set is not compact.
- If $|u_n|$ is bounded, then $K$ maps a bounded set to a set whose closure is not compact.

Your proof got confused in the first step

Comment: acutally, where does 2 follows from 1? We are not trying to show that the closure of the orthonormal $Ku_n$ set are not compact

Answer (score -1):

Remember that a compact operator is continuous, You use continuity when said 
$Ku_{n}\rightarrow Ku$. Thus the proof is fine.